# Volume of a solid formed as vertical limit goes to infinity

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Here's the question:

[image: The question]

The way I have it set up currently is as follows:

$V = \pi \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_1^a (a-1)^2 - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5}} - 1)^2$

But how do I go from here? And is the working thus far okay? Note that I do not have access to a graphing calculator or WolframAlpha in this scenario.

Update:

So I've determined that the $\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^5}} = 0$

and as such decided to compute this as the volume:

$V = \pi \int_0^1 (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5}} - 1)^2$

I ended with: $\frac{15\pi}{4}$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the $\text{d}x$ on your integrals. Aside from that, the area is

\begin{align}
\int_1^a \pi (1 - x^{-5/2})^2 \ \text{d} x &= \pi \left[ \frac{4}{3x^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{4x^4} + x \right]_1^a \\
&= \pi \left[\frac{4}{3a^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{4a^4} + a - \frac{25}{12} \right] \\
\end{align}

Hence,

$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_1^a \pi (1 - x^{-2/5})^2 \ \text{d} x = \infty.$$

So, the volume diverges to infinity as $a$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Are you sure? It's not $x^(-\frac{1}{5})$. Shouldn't it be $x^(-\frac{5}{2})$?

Comment: It's 1 over the square root of $x^5$. If I'm correct, that means it's the negative half root of $x^5$ and should be equal to x^(-5/2).

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Whoops - I fixed it.

Comment: Are you certain you fixed it? It appears as $x^\frac{-2}{5}$ when I believe it should be $x^\frac{-5}{2}$.

Comment: Fixed, hopefully for the last time. It appears my Calculus II skills aren't as sharp as I've remembered - It's been a while. Anyhow, it's still divergent.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks (from Toronto)! I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Your welcome from Vancouver :). Good luck with Calculus II, It was a fun course.